# Output computation strategy problem

Tags: c#

Maybe not the best title I can think of but my problem is this:

I have to design a C# application which takes a bunch of inputs, perform some computation on the input according to a bunch of rules to get a set of results.

The problem is that the rules can change as an when required. To complicate things, many of them are cross tab look ups and conditionals. For example,

```
public string rule_GetFruitForThisSeason(Hamper design)
{
    // crosstab of 2 properties of values 400 to 100 and 600 to 500 respectively.
    if(design.pty1 > 400 && design.pty > 600) return "Apple";
    else if(design.pty1 > 200 && design.pty > 600) return "Pear";
    else if(design.pty1 > 100 && design.pty > 600) return "Orange";
    else if(design.pty1 > 400 && design.pty > 500) return "Grape";
    else if(design.pty1 > 200 && design.pty > 500) return "Berry";
    else if(design.pty1 > 100 && design.pty > 500) return "Peach";
}
```

And then during the next season, all the fruits might change again! (even the conditionals may change.) Ideally, I don't want the programmer to change the fruits every season. The Hamper Designers should be able to do it themselves.

Worse still there could be rules that depend on the output for example

```
public string rule_GetBoxForFruit(string fruit)
{
   if(fruit == "Apple" || fruit == "Pear" || fruit == "orange" || fruit == "peach") return "big box";
   else return "small box";
}
```

I have been thinking through various methods and currently I am using excel for its LOOKUP() and generally ability to evaluate formulas, and then directly reading the excel results. But it is still a huge cumbersome task.

Anyone has any ideas on how to approach this in a better way? Thank you.

Comment: One word. huh? Could you kindly elaborate? To clarify, there are no fixed sets of fruits I can define in code. Future fruits are not predictable.

Comment: Seems you have some example rules ang just need to dig deeper to find the underlying more fundamental rules. Could be table-based (lookup) or maybe a rule engine.

Comment: And in your last example I can't see how a rule depends on an output.

Comment: @Henk Holterman in the last snippet I am trying to show that the output for the first rule is used in the second rule. Are there examples of "table-based (lookup)" and "rule engine" you can show? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you could approach this type of problem, but the main concept is to separate your data from your code.  One approach for doing so is to encapsulate your rules into an XML file, and then use the values in the XML file to manage your logic.  For instance, a file like the following may contain all your rules:

```
<configuration>
    <hamper>
       <seasonalRules>
          <!-- select first rule where 
               design.pty1 > pty1 and design.pty2 > pty2
          -->
          <rule pty1="400" pty="600" fruit="apple" />
          <rule pty1="200" pty="600" fruit="pear" />
          <rule pty1="100" pty="600" fruit="orange" />
          <!-- similar for remaining -->
       </seasonalRules>
    </hamper>
    <fruits>
       <fruit name="apple" box="smallBox" />
       <fruit name="berry" box="smallBox" />
    </fruits>
    <boxes>
       <box name="smallBox" size="small" />
       <box name="largeBox" size="large" />
    </boxes>
</configuration>
```

Then you could use XML to Linq (or any XML API) to read the file and conduct your logic:

```
// ConfigurationData is loaded as
// XDocument.Load("file.xml").Root

public string rule_GetFruitForThisSeason(Hamper design)
{
        var node = ConfigurationData.Elements("hamper")
            .Elements("seasonalRules")
            .Elements("rule")
            .Where(a => int.Parse(a.Attribute("pty1").Value) > design.pty1 &&
                        int.Parse(a.Attribute("pty").Value) > design.pty)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        if (node == null) return null;
        return node.Attribute("fruit").Value;
}
```

Since this code compares business constants, the configuration constants in the XML file can change without changing the corresponding code.  You could also develop a utility that saves configuration data to the XML file that the hamper designers could use themselves to change the computation rules.